# How to add jQuery in Content Query Web Part

Tags: javascript, jquery

How could I add a jQuery in Content Query web Part. How It could be run, not in a head section of template. I have got a jQuery library added and I adding a code and it haven't been fired:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>

<button id="hide">Hide</button>
<button id="show">Show</button>

<p>If you click on the "Hide" button, I will disappear.
<br />
Bo po to jest to wśród nas.
</p>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script  type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
//ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function(){
    $("#hide").click(function(){
        $("p").hide(5000);
    });
    $("#show").click(function(){
        $("p").show(2000);
    });
//},"sp.js");
});


</script>

</body>
</html>
```

This is Sharepoint 2013.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you didnt state what version of sharepoint your using. Assuming 2010/2013 i would use "sharepoint html form web part" instead to insert custom html and Jquery... its what it was designed for. Just put that webpart on the page and copy paste your code above into the text box area and save the webpart.

**edit**

below is what your looking for in 2013

[image]

also change your code to:

```
<button id="hide">Hide</button>
<button id="show">Show</button>

<p>If you click on the "Hide" button, I will disappear.
<br />
Bo po to jest to wśród nas.
</p>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script  type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
//ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function(){
    $("#hide").click(function(){
        $("p").hide(5000);
    });
    $("#show").click(function(){
        $("p").show(2000);
    });
//},"sp.js");
});


</script>
```

no need for head and body! it will throw errors as you already have both in the parent.

**EDIT 2**

try this code instead:

```
<button id="idhide" type="button" onclick="hide();">Hide</button>

<button id="idshow" type="button" onclick="show();">Show</button>

<div id="showhide">
<p>If you click on the "Hide" button, I will disappear.
<br />
Bo po to jest to wśród nas.
</p>
<div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

function hide()
{
         $("#showhide p").hide(5000);
}
function show()
{
        $("#showhide p").show(2000);
}


</script>
```

or

your code slightly modified, need to put in type in the button so that it knows its a button and doesn't produce a postback when referencing a javascript event.

```
<button type="button" id="idhide">Hide</button>
<button type="button" id="idshow">Show</button>

<p>If you click on the "Hide" button, I will disappear.
<br />
Bo po to jest to wśród nas.
</p>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script  type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
//ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function(){
    $("#idhide").click(function(){
        $("p").hide(5000);
    });
    $("#idshow").click(function(){
        $("p").show(2000);
    });
//},"sp.js");
});


</script>
```

Comment: Sharepoint 2013

Comment: unless your doing somthing specific with the cqwp like querying a list and then want a custom UI then I would use SPD to edit the xsl. otherwise just use the html webpart to put in custom html and jquery.... far easier... even when doing a query to a list as you can use rest to get the data instead without having to mess with xsl and rebuilding it into the cqwp.

Comment: Have You got a samles of Code ? Please give some.

Comment: How to find Out HTML Web Part ?

Comment: what type of site are you using? publishing site?

Comment: I using wiki Page Site

Comment: i think in 2013 its been renamed to "Form Content Editor" under Miscellaneous section

Comment: In Content Edictor Jquery is don't run to :(

Comment: ok, in the webpart list under "media and content" add "script editor". that should allow your html to render and should kick off your JS code

Comment: just amended my answer

Comment: Yes i willtry it too but I think that it should be Delay Function to jQuery

Comment: no need as it should be the last to load as it is. This is usually needed if your using some code that is referencing something else on the page that is using the sharepoint JS. what your doing $(document).ready is sufficient

Comment: updated my answer with your updated code that you should add.

Comment: It only fire the buton, but not hide <p>. And it is only on Sharepoint.

Comment: If I use on HTML file or HTM it's work great.

Comment: just amended my answer. both versions work fine ;) , looks like its causing a postback on the code so added type. my code targets a specific within a div

Comment: Now it's working. I don't know why, but it's working :)

Comment: So it's why i hvent got type button ;) Great solution ;)

Comment: In added only button, and work great :)